# Anyway to disable the auto excerpt creation?

Tags: javascript, api, headless

I am using Wordpress as a headless CMS and getting the posts from the API endpoint in 11ty and I'm wondering if you can disable the auto excerpt generation? I know you can do it in PHP but I can't do that in my environment.

Comment: If you're `GET`ting the posts from the API, can you not simply ignore the `excerpt` field and use `content.rendered`?

Comment: Hey @PatJ, yeah you can but I guess I want the option to display the excerpt only if it exist whereas using a modified `content.rendered` will always render for every post.